# ransack sort_link based on a definition method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

i'm using ransack for my application and trying to create a table head sortable with sort_link, but I'm stuck when i try to applied the sort_link to the table head which contains the value not from the table of the database, but from the method in the model...

this is my code

my model

```
def final_price_with_items
  self.item_cost + self.final_price
end
```

and i had a whitelisted in my model to declare the other table head which contains the value from the table of the database.

```
self.whitelisted_ransackable_attributes = ['number','state', 'cost', 'created_at']
```

my html

```
 <table class="index" id="listing_shipments" data-hook>
  <thead>
    <tr data-hook="admin_shipments_index_headers">
      <th><%= sort_link @search, :created_at,  Spree::Shipment.human_attribute_name(:created_at) %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @search, :number,  Spree::Shipment.human_attribute_name(:number) %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @search, :state,  Spree::Shipment.human_attribute_name(:state) %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @search, :cost,  Spree::Shipment.human_attribute_name(:cost) %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link @search, :final_price_with_items,  Spree::Shipment.human_attribute_name(:final_price) %></th>
      <th data-hook="admin_shipments_index_header_actions" class="actions"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @shipments.each do |shipment|%>
      <tr id="<%= spree_dom_id shipment %>" data-hook="admin_shipments_index_rows" class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even')%>">
        <td><%= l shipment.created_at.to_date %></td>
        <td><%= link_to shipment.number, edit_admin_order_path(shipment.order) %></td>
        <td><span class="state <%= shipment.state.downcase %>"><%= Spree.t("shipment_state.#{shipment.state.downcase}") %></span></td>
        <td><%= shipment.display_cost.to_html %></td>
        <td><%= Spree::Money.new(shipment.final_price_with_items, currency: shipment.currency).to_html %></td>
        <td data-hook="admin_shipments_index_row_actions" class="actions align-center">
          <%= link_to_edit_url edit_admin_order_path(shipment.order), :title => "admin_edit_#{dom_id(shipment)}", :no_text => true %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the table head which declared in whitelisted able to sorting, because the shipment table in database had these column, but the final_price_with_items not work to sorting.. anyone can help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to do it with a ransacker. I'd maybe change the the name of your sort link to `final_price_with_items_sort`

Then in your model add this:

`ransacker :final_price_with_items_sort do
  Arel.sql('item_cost + final_price')
end`